# Azure DevOps YML Pipeline different git checkout to Classic

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a large Repository, so we take profit that *Classic* pipelines only make differential checkouts. That means a huge time saving, when the pipeline had a full checkout before.

I start to convert these pipelines from *Classic* to *YML* and recognize that the *YML* checkout task is different from the *Classic* checkout task.

#### YML Checkout (more than 5 min)

```
git version
git version 2.26.2.windows.1
git lfs version
git-lfs/2.10.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.12.7; git a526ba6b)
git init "D:\AzureDevOpsData\agents\MyAgent\_work\20\s"
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/AzureDevOpsData/agents/MyAgent/_work/20/s/.git/
git remote add origin https://MyUrl.com/MyCol/MyProj/_git/MyRepo
git config gc.auto 0
git config --get-all http.https://MyUrl.com/MyCol/MyProj/_git/MyRepo.extraheader
git config --get-all http.proxy
git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" -c http.proxy="http://www-cache.de:3128" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
remote: Azure Repos
```

#### CLASSIC Checkout (less than 10 sec)

```
git version
git version 2.26.2.windows.1
git lfs version
git-lfs/2.10.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.12.7; git a526ba6b)
git config --get remote.origin.url
git clean -ffdx
git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at c349f0e90c0 MyCommit
git config gc.auto 0
git config --get-all http.https://MyUrl.com/MyCol/MyProj/_git/MyRepo.extraheader
git config --get-all http.proxy
git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" -c http.proxy="http://www-cache.de:3128" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
remote: Azure Repos
```

#### Difference

[image]

How can I achieve that the *YML* checkout behave like *Classic* checkout?

**Metainformation**

```
Version: 18.170.30525.1 (Azure DevOps Server 2020)
OnPrem
Self-Hosted-Agents (Windows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yaml supports incremental checkout. Here is a simple example:

```
trigger:
- master

pool: Default

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

The first run:

[image]

The second run:

[image]

Check the following:

1. You use the same build agent for each build of your build definition.
2. Clean options in your build definition ([Clean the local repo on the agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#clean-the-local-repo-on-the-agent)). [Clean build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#clean-build):

> In general, for faster performance of your self-hosted agents, don't
> clean the repo. In this case, to get the best performance, make sure
> you're also building incrementally by disabling any Clean option of
> the task or tool you're using to build.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found the reason. I was using a `workspace clean` instead of a `checkout clean`. Sorry for blaming the checkout it self.